# XCode autocomplete not working for a particular project in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, autocomplete, xcode9.3-beta

I am currently on XCode Beta Version 9.3 beta 2 (9Q107o. I am facing some issues with a particular project. Autocomplete seems to have broken for the project. Its working fine for other projects.

Can anyone please help. Can't seem to figure out.

Thanks

Comment: it is _beta_, it could be full of glitches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autocomplete working in Xcode is by no means guaranteed and definitely not for a beta. Try quitting everything, deleting your derived data, restarting your computer and if that doesn't work, go back to a supported version.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as @Alper say, If it doesn't work. try restore Xcode to the default Settings ,than restarting your Xcode

This is the officially recommended way to delta Xcode preferences, type in Terminal.app:
`defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode`
That should restore Xcode to the state of its first launch.

(for older versions of Xcode the command was `defaults delete com.apple.Xcode`, i.e. without the `dt` in the middle).